# Creating a new mysql AUTO INCREMENT column from hibernate entity class

Tags: mysql, hibernate, auto-increment

From the sources of information in stack overflow, I have understood that we can *use* an already created auto increment column in mysql table using the **@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)** annotation below:

```
@Id
@Column(name="employee_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
```

But suppose, we need to actually create a new table from hibernate with the id column as AUTO INCREMENT (so that we don't have to manually go to the database and alter the column properties to AUTO INCREMENT), can you please let me know the appropriate annotation to use in the entity class?

I already have the config file entry as below:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

I want to *create* an id column with AUTO INCREMENT property in mysql database programmatically from hibernate.

I have tried the annotation **@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)**, but this only makes use of a manually created auto increment column, it doesn't actually create one.

Answer (score 0):

As MySQL doesn't have sequences Hibernate creates a table `hibernate_sequence` to simulate sequences. You can decide whether you would like to use a global sequence for all tables in db schema or dedicated one for each table. As this library is somehow more abstract and this particular mechanism is out of support. You can use `IDENTITY` but it's recommended to use this sequence table instead. Please read following post: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/generated-value-strategy-auto/6481/2 .

If you really want to use auto-increment you can try (Hibernate 5):

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
@GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
```

following https://thorben-janssen.com/5-things-you-need-to-know-when-using-hibernate-with-mysql/#2_Mappings_Problems_with_GenerationTypeAUTO_in_Hibernate_5